# sphinx setlimits isn't working

Tags: php, sql, database, full-text-search, sphinx

I'm using sphinx and everything seems to be working fine except for the SetLimits, I have only 3 records in the index, when I use $cl->SetLimits(0,2) it returns 2 results. 
And when I use $cl->SetLimits(1,2) I also got 2, and when I use $cl->SetLimits(1,2) I got nothing.

This is my understanding of the setlimits

```
$cl->SetLimits(0,2);// should return the first two matches
$cl->SetLimits(1,2);// should return only one as I have only 3 records in the index
$cl->SetLimits(2,2);// should return nothing
```

This is what I inserted in the db

```
insert into tindex values('1','test');
insert into tindex values('2','test');
insert into tindex values('3','test');
```

and I can see it when I select the index.

The php code is below

```
$keywords = "test";
$index = "tindex"; 
$cl = new SphinxClient();
$cl->SetServer( "127.0.0.1", 9312 );
$cl->SetMatchMode( SPH_MATCH_ANY  );        
$cl->SetLimits(1,2);

$result = $cl->Query( $keywords, $index  );

if ( $result === false ) {
    echo "Query failed: " . $cl->GetLastError() . ".\n";
}
else {
    if ( $cl->GetLastWarning() ) {
        echo "WARNING: " . $cl->GetLastWarning() . "";
    }

    if ( ! empty($result["matches"]) ) {
        foreach ( $result["matches"] as $doc => $docinfo ) {

        } 
        print_r( $result );


    }
}
```

Comment: found the problem, I have a problem with the first one, it's offset and not page number :)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly I follow this Prototype: function Set Limits ( $offset, $limit, $max_matches=0, $cutoff=0 ) refereed from http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setlimits